# bundle exec rails generate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think my bundle exec rails generate command is broken (do i make sense?)

I'm getting this all the time when I generate something:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    29: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    28: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    27: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    26: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    25: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    24: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    23: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    22: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    21: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    20: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<main>'
    19: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    18: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    17: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    16: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    15: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    14: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:17:in `perform'
    13: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:8:in `help'
    12: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:15:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    11: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    10: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
     9: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
     8: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     7: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     3: from /Users/YickTing/workspace/ecommerce/config/application.rb:9:in `<main>'
     2: from /Users/YickTing/workspace/ecommerce/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Ecommerce>'
     1: from /Users/YickTing/workspace/ecommerce/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:81:in `load_defaults': Unknown version "5.2" (RuntimeError)
```

Could someone enlighten me what's going on and how to fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your running rails version 5.1.6 but declaring 5.2 in your load file.

I was able to replicate your error in a test app by changing 'load_defaults' to load version 5.2 instead of version 5.1, my current rails version. The relevant line is located in your config/application.rb file.

```
config.load_defaults 5.2
```

Kinda hard to replicate the issue further (simply changing it back to 5.1 eliminates the error message for me), but the [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application/Configuration.html#method-i-load_defaults) docs have some info on load_defaults that might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 

I followed your instruction to change to 5.1, the error message has now become something else though.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle` or `bundle install` first. Make sure you can also run other commands successfully such as `bundle exec rails c` to check if it's a general config issue (more likely, given the "5.2" error here) or a specific issue with generate.

Comment: yes, it turns out to be a general config issue, any suggestion to fixed that? thanks.

Comment: Did you try to run bundle first?

Comment: Yes, I did run bundle first.

Comment: problem fixed! I had to uninstall rails and install all over again :)